# How to generate a single line break in a Laravel Markdown Mailable

Tags: laravel, markdown

Here is the mailable template:

```
@component('mail::message')
Address line 1
Address line 2
Address line 3
@endcomponent
```

Here is the generated HTML:

```
<p style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; color: #74787E; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">Address line 1
Address line 2
Address line 3</p>
```

When you display this in a brower...

Address line 1
Address line 2
Address line 3

So, I have seen several other SO questions on this but they did not solve my issue.  I have tried following each line with two spaces, and also with a backslash.  Neither has had any effect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, it's always possible to combine markdown and HTML:

```
@component('mail::message')
Address line 1<br>
Address line 2<br>
Address line 3<br>
@endcomponent
```

Another approach is, to use the new line character `\n` and parse it with `nl2br()`:

```
@component('mail::message')
{!! nl2br("Address line 1\n Address line 2\n Address line 3") !!}
@endcomponent
```

Note: `nl2br()` only works, if the string is in double quotes!

I also like the table component:

```
@component('mail::table')
| Addresses      |
| -------------- |
| Address line 1 |
| Address line 2 |
| Address line 3 |
@endcomponent
```

One more thing: Instead of having all the content in your template files consider refactoring to [notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/master/notifications#mail-notifications). Notifications also support being sent as an email and make it possible to reuse the mail template for other emails. (This will not help you regarding the new lines though.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want use standard mail template and change only specific part of it then you can create custom fragment class which implements `Htmlable` interface

```php
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Models\Payment;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Htmlable;

class PaymentMailDetails implements Htmlable
{

    private Payment $payment;

    public function __construct(Payment $payment)
    {
        $this->payment = $payment;
    }

    /**
     * Get content as a string of HTML.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function toHtml(): string
    {
        return "New Payment:<br>"
            . "**Amount:** {$this->payment->amount}<br>"
            . "**Name:** {$this->payment->user_name}<br>"
            . "**Email:** {$this->payment->user_email}<br>"
            . "**Comment:** {$this->payment->comment}";
    }
}
```

And then in your notification class use this class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Models\Payment;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class NewPaymentNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    private Payment $payment;

    public function __construct(Payment $payment)
    {
        $this->payment = $payment;
    }

    public function via($notifiable): array
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable): MailMessage
    {
        $details = new PaymentMailDetails($this->payment);
        $url = url('/payments/' . $this->payment->id);
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('New payment')
            ->line($details)
            ->action('Show payment details', $url);
    }

}
```

Using this idea you able to create any type of html fragments for your mails